# How to change isolation level in mysql shell JavaScript mode?

Tags: mysql, document-store

I was learning MySQL Document store. And I learnt that the read isolation actually has different isolation levels in the document store, but I don't know how to set the transaction isolation in MySQL shell in JS mode.

I use JS mode because the tutorial in modify collections is in JS code.

Please help me with this, is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out when in MySQL shell, the session is global which means the isolation level is the same no matter in js or SQL mode. So it is ok to set isolation level in SQL mode and switch to js mode